# Shell Parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, bash-expansion

I've got done the following  parameter shell expansion:

```
trihead="$(cat ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa)"
echo "${trihead#"${trihead%%[!A]*}"}" > ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa
```

I'd like to trim the leading A's from the second line of a fasta file (a kind of plain text format .fa)

the input would be something like:

```
>B4-0K032_18670_015
AAAAAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNNGNNNTAGATACAAGCGAGCGGC
```

and i'd like the output to be like:

```
>B4-0K032_18670_015
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNNGNNNTAGATACAAGCGAGCGGC
```

By the way, does anybody know some side where shell parameter expansion is well explained?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain i) what the command is supposed to be doing and  ii) what it is actually doing. Also, this isn't a bioinformatics site, people here have no idea what FASTA is. Please include an example of your input file and show us the output you would like to see.

Comment: Don't read a [fasta file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) into a variable. It looks more like this is a job for `sed` or `awk`, depending on what it is you're trying to achieve on that second line.

Comment: Edited sorry! I though about sed sth like sed -e '4 {all leading A's}' > file but iunno how to order sed to delete leading A's from 2nd line not all A's or so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trim the leading consecutive `A`s out of the *second* line of a file (and then replace the original file with the result):

```
$ sed '2s/^A*//' data.fa >data.out  &&  mv data.out data.fa
```

The `sed` command applies the substitution command (`s`) to line 2 specifically in this example. It will substitute any number of `A`s at the start of the line with nothing.

The pattern is `^A*` which means "match zero or more (`*`) of the single character `A` at the start of the line (`^`)".

The reason I don't use `sed -i` (for "in-place editing") is that the `-i` flag is horribly non-portable between `sed` implementations.

Comment: so to order A leading characters do u use ^ ? for trimming tailing A's you do sed '/^N*//g' file

Comment: `^` is the regular expression anchor for "Start of the line".

Comment: @Neuls The `^` is called an "anchor". It anchors the pattern (`A*`) to the start of the line. The anchor for the end or the line is `$`.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all leading `A`s from a line following a line that start with `>`:

```
sed '/^>/n;s/^A*//' /path/to/file
```

If the output is what you want, and you want to edit the original file, use:

```
sed --in-place '/^>/n;s/^A*//' /path/to/file
```